# "says so vs says that ..."

Tags: sentence-construction, optional-that

I just wanted to ask if these sentences mean the same thing.

> She always shows up right when she's said she'll.

For me, this sentence is clearly understood. But:

> She always shows up right when she's said so.

What about replacing it with "so?" - I personally find it a bit convoluted but I am not sure.

*Is there a stylistic difference or preference?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not use shorted forms at the end of expressions like 'right when she's said **she'll**" here, we would use the full form 'she will'. Also we would not use 'when she's said so.' You could write 'She always shows up right when she says she will'. I would use the present 'she says' because you are using the present 'shows' to discuss a habitual action.